Get service health statistics for OSB services from oracle EM using restful?
I am using oracle enterprise management to monitor a set of services deployed on an osb cluster, I following this in console:
target --> SOA --> service bus --> services health tab
now, what I wat is to automate the process of gathering these info, therefore I need an endpoint to retrieve these info, I have done some researches but I could not find any,
any idea about this, or if there other mechanism to retrieve these info... thanks in advance
